# Sign in using Cucumber and Devise fails with no message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, bdd

This feature worked a bit, then stopped working.

```
Background:
  Given a user is logged in
  Then I should see "Signed in successfully."
```

With

```
Given /^a user is logged in$/ do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @user.confirm!
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'Email', :with => @user.email
  fill_in 'Password', :with => @user.password
  click_on 'Sign in'
end

Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |message|
   page.should have_content(message)
end
```

`Given a user is logged` in passes but `Then I should see "Signed in successfully."` fails with the error `expected there to be content "Signed in successfully."`. **It stays in the sign in page**.

Anyone has an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Notice that I don't like to be too specific in the feature description as the client does not really care about the details. I'd rather be in the steps.

Comment: The `new` action in the sessions controller might be failing to authenticate the user and thus re-rendering the sign-in page

Comment: The authentication works with the browser. It's definitely something with the steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

I changed

```
click_on 'Sign in'
```

to

```
click_button 'Sign in'
```

It's weird that Capybara did not complain about not finding a `Sign in` to click on.

Thanks everyone for your comments and answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [launchy](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy) to your test gemspec group and calling `save_and_open_page` after clicking on 'Sign in' - this should help you see whether anything is wrong with your login process.

Comment: If you have no error message, then that means that either the session controller is not redirecting the user to the appropiate action after a successfull login, or it doesn't show an error message when the login is not successful.